# Unit testing emberjs component that contains a "link-to"

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I'm using the ember-qunit moduleForComponent helper, which is working great.

The problem is that when I test the rendered HTML `@$('.myclass')`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
```

Associated HBS file contains:

```
{{#link-to 'units.options' (query-params categoryId=category.id)}}
```

Unit test contains:
    `import { test, moduleForComponent } from 'ember-qunit'`

```
`import Router from 'appkit/router'`

moduleForComponent('category-card')

test 'card title', ->
  component = @subject()

  Ember.run ->
    component.set 'category', Ember.Object.create(id: 34, name: 'extra large')

  equal(@$('.card-title').text(), 'extra large')
```

It would seem that I need to stub out the **router**. Any tips?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
    at computeLinkViewRouteArgs (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:37627:66)
    at ComputedPropertyPrototype.get (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:4926:38)
    at get (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:2151:17)
    at computeLinkViewLoading (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:37493:12)
    at ComputedPropertyPrototype.get (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:4926:38)
    at get (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:2151:17)
    at computeLinkViewActive (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:37463:11)
    at ComputedPropertyPrototype.get (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:4926:38)
    at get (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:2151:17)
    at Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._classStringForProperty (http://localhost:7359/vendor/ember/ember.js:23738:15)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from the error that you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
setup: ->
    store = QUnit.Helpers.configureStore @container
    Ember.LinkView.reopen({
      href: '#'
      loading: {}
    })
```